# Regarding product form of Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Can I consider: $\cos(x)=(1+a_0)(1+a_1x)(1+a_2x^2)\cdots$?

Taking the logarithm on both sides and differentiating gives:
($a_0$ considered to be $0$)

$-\tan(x)=\dfrac{a_1}{a_1x+1}+\dfrac{2a_2x}{a_2x^2+1}+\cdots; a_1=0$

$-\sec^2(x)=\dfrac{-2a_2(a_2x^2-1)}{(a_2x^2+1)^2}+\cdots; a_2=\dfrac{-1}{2}$

And so on,

$a_2=\dfrac{-1}{2},a_2=\dfrac{1}{12},a_2=\dfrac{-1}{45},\cdots$

$\cos(x)=(1-\dfrac{1\cdot x^2}{2!})\cdot(1+\dfrac{2\cdot x^4}{4!})\cdot(1-\dfrac{16\cdot x^6}{6!})\cdot(1+\dfrac{272\cdot x^8}{8!})\cdots$, Where $1,2,16,272,7936,353792,\cdots$ are "Zag numbers" https://oeis.org/A000182

Is this series representation wrong? If so, why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Infinite_product_formulae

Comment: Thank you, but the formulae mentioned here have a uniform power in $x$. By that I mean they are infinite products but with only $x^2$'s coefficients. What I have a doubt regarding is if Taylor expansions can be extended to represent functions as infinite products with differing powers of $x$.

Comment: This can always be done formally (in the sense that a formal power series with constant term $1$ has a unique expression in this form, by induction) and then it's just a matter of checking convergence.